# How to integrate between a Spring @Service and a non Spring object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have some `@Service FooService` which on request, makes an API call to some external service and returns some `FooResult`.

In my project I defined some `FooTask`. This is actually a wrapper of a `java.util.Function` (and it being used in some `CompletableFuture` chain)

Ideally, I'd like the task to call `FooService.request()`. One solution could be injecting the `FooService` in the constructor but I'm not sure that's a good idea.

What is the Spring way to do that?

Comment: Simply inject it. Why do you think it's not a good idea?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli as far as I understand the issue, the `FooResult` is created by calling `new FooResult(...)` within the `FooService`, thus the task is not a Spring-bean and autowiring will not work. It would be possible to give `FooResult` a field of type `FooService` and call `fooResult.setFooService(this)` within `FooService`, when the result is received from the external API.

Comment: Sure you can pass the service as a reference to the task

Answer (score 2):

I don't think using `FooTask` as a Spring `Component`(a class which is annotated with `@Component` annotation) causes any problem if your `FooTask` is a `Functional` Wrapper and does not save any state, However if your `FooTask` maintain some state or you want to create multiple instances of that somewhere in your application you can create instances of `FooTask` outside Spring framework and autowire `FooService` in it, this is exactly possible using `AutowiredCapableBeanFactory` but don't go for this approach unless it is necessary:

Do it this way to `autowire` your `FooService` in `FooTask`:

```
private @Autowired
AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;
public void doSomething() {
    FooTask fooTask = new FooTask();
    beanFactory.autowireBean(fooTask);
    // obj will now have its dependencies autowired.
}
```

Comment: It may be easier to inject directly FooService using the constructor to avoid coupling with Spring API.